# Помогите разобраться с Events

Tags: c#, многопоточность, события

```
private void Button_Run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Camera_translation();
    }
    private void Camera_translation()
    {
        Capture capture = new Capture();

        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(delegate (object sender1, EventArgs e1)
        {

            this.camera_image.Image = capture.QueryFrame();
            this.camera_image.Update();

        });
    }

    private void Button_Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //должен прекращаться показ с камеры 
    }
```

Comment: @Igor Application.Idle имеет только 2 оператора += и -=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void Button_Run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CameraConnect();
}

EventHandler handler = null;

private void CameraConnect()
{
  CameraDisconnect();

  Capture capture = new Capture();

  handler = new EventHandler(delegate (object sender1, EventArgs e1)
  {
    this.camera_image.Image = capture.QueryFrame();
    this.camera_image.Update();
  };
  Application.Idle += handler;
}

private void Button_Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CameraDisconnect(); 
}

private void CameraDisconnect()
{
  if (handler != null)
  {
    Application.Idle -= handler;
    handler = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: @VladD - конечно, спасибо

Comment: Я бы ещё проверил `handler` в `Camera_translation`, но это мне показалось слишком большим изменением.

Comment: Не за что, это была явная опечатка :)

Comment: @VladD я как раз печатал

Comment: @Igor Спасибо!!